# get modified result from 2 tables

Tags: sql, derby

I have 2 tables:

### table1

```
id  |   name
-----------------------------------------
1   |   abc
2   |   def
```

### table2

```
table1id    |   nr_name |   nr_val
-----------------------------------------
1           |   7       |   123
1           |   9       |   321
2           |   7       |   432
```

What SQL code do I need to get this result?

### result

```
id  |   name    |   nr7 |   nr9
-----------------------------------------
1   |   abc     |   123 |   321
2   |   def     |   432 |   0
```

nr_name can only be 7 or 9 and I can't change the structure of table2 
(I will add more nr_name types later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.nr_name = 7 THEN t2.nr_val END) AS 'nr7',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.nr_name = 9 THEN t2.nr_val END) AS 'nr9'
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN  table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1id
WHERE t2.name IN (7, 9)
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,
       CASE WHEN t2.nr_name = 7 THEN t2.nr_val ELSE 0 END AS 'nr7',
       CASE WHEN t2.nr_name = 9 THEN t2.nr_val ELSE 0 END AS 'nr9'
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN  table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1id
WHERE t2.name IN (7,9)
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: I also tried your version, but don't know how to use it without max function. If I remove max() then I have to remove group by, so I got new line for every case (7 or 9).